# What is the proper way to create control in Xamarin Form PCL?

Tags: xamarin.forms

What is the proper way to create control in Xamarin Form PCL?

In my class library I have "control" class not derived from any View, just a layout with some labels, scrollviews, logic etc.
I am using it in my pages in the same PLC in several places.

My question is - what is the proper way to wrap this "control" and use it in PLC pages? 
I ended up having this control class to expose its root layout where I add all the child elements and subsequently add this layout to the children of page layout. This makes this class to be some sort of a builder of a part of UI of a page.

It looks like that using "View" as a base class requires me to add custom renderers to Android and iOS projects
which I don't need to do - all my UI functionality fits into PCL withot the need for any custom work.

I have a feeling that I am not doing it the right way.

Advise and/or link to the documentation on how to properly do it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need custom renderers? Why can't you use `ContentView` as a base class and set `ContentView.Content` as the main layout?

Comment: That's the whole point, I don't need custom renderers. I am just trying to organize the code in PCL that would allow me do so something like that:
... Children.Add (new myControl_inPCL());
instead of:
var mycontrol = new myControl_inPCL();
...Children.Add(mycontrol.layout);

Comment: Ah, I understand! Give me a few.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you're actually hurting yourself by not wanting to use a `View` as a base class. I commonly use `ContentView` as a base class to create my own controls and it works great without the need for a custom renderer since ContentView already has its own renderers in iOS and Android. Something like this should do the trick.

```
public class MyContentView : ContentView
{
    private Layout createLayout();

    public MyContentView()
    {
        Content = createLayout();
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, ContentView is what I needed. Thanks!